# Another word instead of agent / agency for someone who sells on behalf of another

Tags: synonyms

I am starting a company and it is essentially bringing the estate agent model to another market.

I will be selling other persons products for them from taking the imagery to doing the actual selling and handling of finances.

I cannot use the term agency in the name, but cannot find anything else that matches the same meaning.

Broker is not the image we are looking for, any other suggestions?

Comment: "Broker" is one term.

Comment: @HotLicks++. *Broker* is exactly the term; if you don't want the image, then don't live up to it. Else choosing a different term is merely a stay of execution, not a pardon.

Comment: (That said, in the retail world, stores which sell others' [second-hand] goods, and charge the lion's share of the tale for that service, are known is *consignment stores*.)

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for one of **reseller**, **affiliate**, or **broker**.

In business parlance, being a reseller implies that you basically own the client. Think of it as white labeling: you sell *instead of* the original seller under your name. Affiliate, in contrast, means you're pushing leads and picking up a commission on the sale, and putting the company who you're the affiliate of front left and center. A broker brokers deals, as in buys and sells for others, so it's more of a representative kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Excluding *agent* and *broker*, I might recommend *[trader](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trader)*:

> noun
>
> 1 A person who buys and sells goods, currency, or shares.
>
> ODO

Example from [*Renewable Advantage: Crafting Strategy Through Economic Time*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ebKsbjM6h5AC&pg=PA164&dq=%22trader%22%20product&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WY0hVeeGOa60sASwvoHgAQ&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22trader%22%20product&f=false) by Jeffrey Williams, 1998:

> *... the important point is to compensate the **trader** for the quality of her ideas, recognizing that the trader's product line needs
>   to refreshed frequently...*
>
> ***Emphasis*** mine

Answer (score -1):

In the industry, the word **representative** is often used for *"someone who sells on behalf of another."*

> - a person who represents and tries to sell the products or services of a firm, esp a travelling salesman. Often shortened to: rep [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/representative)